# Convert a date to MM/dd/yyyy format with date time data type

Tags: c#, date, datetime

In C#, I want to convert my machine date time - that could be in any format - to MM/dd/yyyy format.
The result should have Date Time data type and not string data type.

I tried following but it not converting to MM/dd/yyyy

```
string ds = "25.05.2016";
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(ds, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt))
        {
            ds = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(ds);
```

Comment: `TryParseExact` means that you know the format beforehand. If you don't, you should use `TryParse`. Even then, though, I don't see how you're going to be able to disambiguate 1/2/2020; it it Jan 2 or Feb 1?

Comment: Yes, I know expected format beforehand but not the input date format. But the machine culture should give information about if date culture is MM/dd or dd/MM

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: If you actually have a string input, as `"25.05.2016"` and not a DateTime input, then TryParseExct would be: `DateTime.TryParseExact(ds, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt))`. The format you pass to `(Try)ParseExact` is the format of the input string, not your *desired* output. If your input is instead a DateTime, you may need to format it, for presentation purposes, in the local short day/time, as, e.g., `ds = dt.ToShortDateString()`. Or use a specific format, when actually needed, as in `ds = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Answer (score 0):

Your code don't work because TryParseExact returns false. I think this is because of your format. The problem with your format is explained in the comments of your question. You can use TryParse:

```
string ds = "25.05.2016";
if (DateTime.TryParse(ds, out DateTime dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Comment: This is not converting date to expected format. I am getting output as 05-25-2016 rather than 05/25/2016. Also the output data type is string. We need output data type as Date Time.

Comment: Still following line of code will provide output in string data type but I need it in DateTime data type. dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: A DateTime always look the same. It don't have any format. You can only create a format of a date with a string. You can use your dt variable if you want to do anything with this date. But if you want to show this date in your format, you have to use ToString.